# how to add the "add content" to menu drupal

Tags: routes, nodes

I want to add my "Add Content" --> Products " into my menu bar for a menu link. How can I achieve this? Thanks. I want to add this for ease of access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate to '`Add Content`" page from admin menu & copy the path after `$base_url`.

Example - If it looks like "`http://example.com/node/add/product`" then copy "`node/add/product`".

Go to your menu and add one more menu item with the **Menu link title** of your choice & put this **node/add/product** in **Path** over there. All the user will have access to this menu item who ever have permission for adding content of this particular content type.

Comment: Thanks :) I see i have included the example.com/node/add/product rather than just the node/add/product

Comment: That also you can do but for internal link you need not to include full URLs...